# Should every module have its service to fetch data? (Angular 2)

Tags: angular

Im currently working on angular 2 application.

Assume i build a new feature module in my app, and this module requires some data from the server, also, i have some global data-services (core-module) that can serve this data to my new module.

My questions is, should i build another service that communicate with these data-services and any component inside my new module will talk only to that service,
or its ok for my components to talk directly to the data-services.

(Assume the data-services have simple crud operations, for example)

My other question is, can a feature-module-service talk directly to server (i.e. make ajax requests) or it should always talk through the data-services for that?

I tried to explain it with a pic, hope it will help..
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is a general question about software design. You might want to try posting it on: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ThinkingMedia when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat yes, I totally agree. I wish that site was listed as one of the close options for off-topic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single generic data service that serves data for your entire application, it would make sense for each component to access it.

If you have more specific data access needs for your feature, then adding a second service to your feature module makes sense even if it in turn calls the generic data service.

It is *not* considered good practice to add http code directly to your component. Separating it out into its own component makes it easier to modify, test, and debug. And it makes it reusable throughout your application.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question. First, feature modules are oriented to use lazy loading more info here https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#angular-modularity
The goal is to load application in modules that are controlled by the router. Second, a service is desirable to be instantiated once and to be available for use everywhere. This is the reason of the core module. Core module will be added in our app.module.ts and will be available everywhere. In conclusion, I don't think it is required to have a service in your feature module just use the service from the core module. For your other question it is possible, but it is not a good practice because probably your service will be instantiated more than once which is something unnecessary and can lead to problems.

hope it helps.